# I don't know why SteamUserStats.GetStat() returns false

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steamworks-api

I want to integrate Unity project to Steam. So I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YzeGHtwS4gE&t=742s).

But I faced the problem.

```
IEnumerator initData () {
    while (!SteamManager.Initialized)
        yield return null;

    Debug.Log (SteamUser.BLoggedOn ());

    int data;
    bool check;

    Debug.Log (SteamUserStats.SetStat ("status", 2));
    check = SteamUserStats.GetStat ("status", out data);
    Debug.Log (check.ToString () + data.ToString ());
    Debug.Log (SteamUserStats.ResetAllStats (true));
}
```

Once I ran this code it showed me a log like this.[image]

And I also did make the stats info and published it before run the code.[image: enter link description here]

I really don't know why `SetStat()` and `GetStat()` methods return false.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read the [ask] page and update your question.

Comment: Did you try this?

"Also, make sure the Steam account you are testing with has sufficient rights to the game, as long as it is not public, yet."

Source:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1303270/using-steamworksnet-steam-callbacks-always-fail-wh.html